# Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'SearchserviceModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular

Im stuck at this point getting this error, hope some of you experts can help me with this. before i added the search bar my website worked fine (just a little project for learning more about angular) i have no idea what is wrong cause i did try to search my app.module for error but i cant see any.

Cheers!

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'SearchserviceModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

```
**My app.module.ts looks like this**



enter code here

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MovielistComponent } from './movielist/movielist.component';
import { SearchserviceModule } from './searchservice/searchservice.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MovielistComponent,
    SearchserviceModule,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
      path: 'movielist',
      component: MovielistComponent
      },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }




**My app.component.ts looks like this** 

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { SearchserviceModule } from './searchservice/searchservice.module';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [SearchserviceModule]
})
export class AppComponent {
  results: Object;
  searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private searchService: SearchserviceModule) {
    this.searchService.search(this.searchTerm$)
      .subscribe(results => {
        this.results = results.results;
      });
  }
}


**My searchservice.module.ts looks like this** 

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Injectable()
export class SearchserviceModule {
  baseUrl: string = 'https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries';
  queryUrl: string = '?search=';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
  }

  searchEntries(term) {
    return this.http
        .get(this.baseUrl + this.queryUrl + term)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add SearchserviceModule to providers not to declarations:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
 AppComponent,
 MovielistComponent

],
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 FormsModule,
 HttpModule,
 RouterModule.forRoot([
   {
   path: 'movielist',
   component: MovielistComponent
   },
])
],
providers: [SearchserviceModule],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
 export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: this answer will fix your issue, i recommand you to rename 'SearchserviceModule' by 'SearchService' in 'search.service.ts' file. Like this you will follow Angular naming standard.

Comment: yes you're right @Yanis-git , SearchserviceModule is confusing, not clear if it's a module or a service